# setting the categories using ajax in highcharts

Tags: ajax, highcharts, categories

trying to create a chart heatmap using `highcharts` library, i am using `blacklabel` plugin to set multilevel categories for x and y axis.

here is the blacklabel demo link.

```
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/TFhd7/
```

if i hardcode the categories as per the demo, its working good, but i get the x axis categories, y axis categories and the data from the database. this is where i am facing issue.

my server side coding is c# with asp.net, and i am posting all ajax calls to request all the data.

can anyone help me with example how to set the multilevel categories dynamically with ajax call.

Comment: How does the categories data look like?

Answer (score 0):

blacklabel demo link https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/TFhd7/

at the above link, xaxis categories are hardcoded.
below is the snippet from the above link.

```
categories: [{
        name: "Fruit",
        categories: ["Apple", "Banana", "Orange"]
    }, {
        name: "Vegetable",
        categories: ["Carrot", "Potato", "Tomato"]
    }, {
        name: "Fish",
        categories: ["Cod", "Salmon", "Tuna"]
    }]
```

now i am trying to generate similar kind of json format by connecting to the DB and sending to the Javascript thru c#.

as i said in my first post that i am facing issues in setting the categories when i get it from the DB, if i hardcode as per the example it works good.

so the solution i found is...
1) return data into json from c# . 
jsonconvert.serializeobject(data)

2) parse the data into json format at the success function of ajax call.
JSON.parse(response)